# CKEditor displaying HTML tags in editor

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am using a CKEditor and saving content to a MySQL database. When trying to edit the content again in the editor, I am getting HTML tags displayed as text, for example:

```
my test<br />and second line
```

How can I have it display in the editor correctly again?

I have been fiddling with htmlentities and html_entity_decode and CKEditor related settings for over an hour now, with no avail.

```
   $config = array();
   $config['enterMode'] = 2;
   $config['shiftEnterMode'] = 1;
   //$config['basicEntities'] = FALSE;
   //$config['entities'] = FALSE;
   //$config['entities_greek'] = FALSE;
   //$config['entities_latin'] = FALSE;
   //$config['htmlDecodeOutput'] = TRUE;

   $ck_editor->editor("sec1_content", $default_value, $config);
```

Comment: try to switch on 'html edit mode' and check what CKE having on input. that should show you direction to dig

Comment: This is what I get when I open the Source mode of CKE: my text&lt;br /&gt; and second line

Comment: have you tried `$ck_editor->editor("sec1_content", html_entity_decode($default_value), $config);` ?

Comment: Yes, and I just tried it again. It gives same output as without... It's driving me nuts, never had any issue with FCK.

Comment: if you'll drop your config and some code into pastebin, i'll try it on my server.

Comment: Well basically that's the code and config together: http://pastebin.com/yEVdkAV5 I only modify config through PHP. Let me know what more information I can provide, and thanks...

Comment: what does set_value function doing?

Comment: Duh!! Good question! That is from the CodeIgniter framework, I just removed it and it work fine. The thought didn't even occur before so I even left it out from the above code!! Now I need to figure out how to fix this CodeIgniter issue. Thanks a lot man, when you spend too much time coding something you become blind.

Comment: Glad i could give you an idea =) good luck!

Comment: easiest workaround is to write it like this `$ck_editor->editor("sec1_content", html_entity_decode(set_value('sec1_content', $default_value)), $config);`

Comment: Indeed! I just posted an answer for people that might come along later. If you post your own answer I will select it as the correct one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that CodeIgniter's func `set_value()` acts like `htmlspecialchars()` in some way. So if you are getting <any_tag> on CKEditor this workaround can help you. Change

```
$ck_editor->editor("sec1_content", set_value('sec1_content', html_entity_decode($default_value)), $config);
```

To this:

```
$ck_editor->editor("sec1_content", html_entity_decode(set_value('sec1_content', $default_value)), $config);
```

> *PoloRM*
>   Put html_entity_decode around set_value. The reason for this is obviously because the set_value method might not use the $default_value parameter but return the posted data instead.

Answer (score 1):

For people who might have the same issue with CodeIgniter/CKEditor:

The way to resolve this issue and still use the CodeIgniter set_value() method is the following:

```
$ck_editor->editor("sec1_content", set_value('sec1_content', html_entity_decode($default_value)), $config);
```

Do this:

```
$ck_editor->editor("sec1_content", html_entity_decode(set_value('sec1_content', $default_value)), $config);
```

Put html_entity_decode around set_value. The reason for this is obviously because the set_value method might not use the $default_value parameter but return the posted data instead.

Thank you coramba for making me realize my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone having this issue in Laravel the `strip_tags` function is helpful.
In the view : `{{ strip_tags($your_content) }}`