# CKEditor : replace HTML tag by effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using **CKEditor** for the content writing. 
It works fine for adding (create content) purpose. and store all HTML effect by HTML tag in the database.

Now what is my problem, when i **open this content in Edit mode**,in CKEditor it displays HTML tags instead of  its effect.

How can i display HTML effect instead of HTML tag.

example,

I have one string "My name is Nisarg".

i choose bold effect from CKEditor.so my string becomes "`<b> My name is Nisarg </b>`" and it store in database like this.

now when i open it for edit , it shows me like this

[image: example]

so how can i remove that tags?

Comment: Looks like the html is converted/escaped as it gets saved or read from the database.

Comment: yes , how can i convert it to its effect?

Comment: When the html is stored, if you are doing any kind of conversion, you need to reverse the conversion when loading it into the editor again. Are you using php?

Comment: i am not doing any conversion at storing, N yes i am using PHP

Comment: Show additional info, how you call ckeditor, how you output data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567285/ckeditor-displaying-html-tags-in-editor?rq=1

Comment: `html_entity_decode()` works for me...solved!

Comment: You can add your solution as an answer or should this be closed/marked as dupe? Unanswered, not closed but solved questions are disturbing.